# Using Leaflet to consume google tiles without labels

Tags: leaflet, labeling, google-maps, tiles, basemap

Using Leaflet, it is possible to consume google maps tiles with the code below:

```
    var googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&',{
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
    });
```

**Is it possible to consume the same service but without labels? Does google provide a tiling service for this purpose?**

I can easily do that with cartodb basemaps because they provide different services for this reason:

```
    var basemapCartoNoLabels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy;OpenStreetMap, &copy;CartoDB'
    }).addTo(map);

    var basemapCartoOnlyLabels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy;OpenStreetMap, &copy;CartoDB',
        pane: 'labels'
    }).addTo(map);
```

My goal is to show the following layers:
- google streets
- my geometry json layer
- labels on top of everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to google's terms&conditions, it's not possible to access the tiles without using their API. For this reason, things like https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant exist.

It *should* be possible to request tiles without labels by using the "custom styling" functionality, but I'm not sure that will allow requesting labels-only tiles.